# Unable to execute ./JLinkExe: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberrypi

I'm using raspberry pi 4 as a host to run the Jlink-plus debugger.

I downloaded the software JLink_Linux_V788c_arm from SEGGER website.
But when I run **sudo ./JLinkExe**, it always said that **sudo: unable to execute ./JLinkExe: No such file or directory**

Is anyone here experienced the same scenario?
Please help me

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details which is a basic starting point.  Providing clues on where you downloaded the file & instructions on the site (*it's an unusual name; did you explore the contents of it according to what your system sees?*) but the basic starting point is always what OS/product & release you're using (differences can exist between Ubuntu's products, Ubuntu Core is limited to *snap* packages only for example)

Comment: are you in the directory where "JLinkExe" is located? are you sure that's what the file is called (no extension)?

Comment: Yes., I'm in the jlink directory when I called the command "sudo ./JlinkExe"

Comment: I really don't know if need an extension but what i've read on other forum, they just called the command "sudo ./JLinkExe" in the jlink directory

Comment: Hello everyone! i already solve my problem. I just downloaded wrong software for Jlink app., Thanks!